# How would I only allow only certain messages to be set users [NODE.JS]

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, node.js

I am working on a mutliplayer game and decided to use NodeJS aspart of the system.
The nodeJS is linked to m c# game emulator via TCP.

However how would I send messages to certain user ID?
Each individual user in the database is sided by a unique user ID (E.G 1)

How can I do this so if a user in game does a certain thing and that sends a message
from Node ONLY TO THEM.

Since I can't run node on the same port as my cms (Port 80). 
I need a method in which I can use PHP to pull the ID or something.

Use as Jquery and 'GET'? I'm suck.

By message I mean data such as sending a javascript window.

Options available:
JQuery
Javascript
PHP
Node

I thought of a method were the user id is presented within a div through a parameter in PHP (E.G $ID) and then javascript checked against the div and the message to see if the ids matched. Then within the message the users ID would be included, then somehow I could split the message? so its "","" (ID,MESSAGE)

Code:

var socket = io.connect('http://dev.com');
  socket.on('field', function (data) {

```
if ($("#userid").text().indexOf(data) > -1)
{   
    window.alert('lol');    
    console.log(data);
    $("#field").html(data);
}
else
{
    window.alert("Something has gone wrong with the node server...");
}
```

});

It didn't work.

THE PAGE:
[image]
THE C#:
[image]
THE NODE:
[image]

Comment: Node.js can be used for just about anything.  You're going to need to be much more specific about how you're using it if you want a useful answer.  It sounds like you just need an AJAX request... but it isn't clear.  Also, just proxy your requests to your Node.js server so you can run Node.js and your regular HTTP stuff on the same public-facing port.

Comment: Yes AJAX request sounds about right, although I'm not sure I would go about the system. Would you mind me showing you on a screenshare? https://join.me/409-609-166 or over StackOverflow.

Comment: Post your specific question and more information here so that the answers can benefit everyone.

Comment: Right I have a database table with users. Each user has a unique key (int) to them. I'd like to Node and AJAX so when a message get sent your node it only goes to that speific user in hand.

Comment: What's in these messages?  How big are the messages?  How often do you need to send them?  Are all messages just to one user, or do you need some to send to multiple users?  Must the messages be generated and queued while the user is offline as well?

Comment: Inside the messages are just html that node sends to the page via a Node HTTP server. The messages aren't big just little things like "<script>window.open("google.com");</script>. Messages are only triggered if a user clicks a certain thing within game and no.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response in the comments:

> Inside the messages are just html that node sends to the page via a Node HTTP server. The messages aren't big just little things like "window.open("google.com");. Messages are only triggered if a user clicks a certain thing within game and no.

It sounds to me like what you really want is some sort of RPC.  There's a solid [NPM module called Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) which wraps all this up nicely for you.  Fire an event, it can be handled server-side, and any callback data gets sent back to the client.

http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: I'm using Socket.io w/Node at the moment.. I just don't know how to get my server to sent a message to the specfic user that triggers it off.

Comment: @user3818791 Right, well messages don't just automatically go to everyone, so you must have written code to do that.  Simply don't do that.  I don't know what else you expect me to tell you.  You haven't shown any code.  How am I supposed to know what you've tried and what you haven't?  From your question it sounds like you didn't know what AJAX was and now you're saying you already have your technology choice solved.  So, if I am to answer your question, I would have to see what you're actually doing in your code... otherwise I don't know what you're stuck on.

Comment: @user3818791 I'm still confused... where are you emitting the `field` event on the server?  Is your question on how to emit that event?  If so, just save a reference to that socket when the user connects and you know its userid.

Comment: I'm new to javascript, I really don't understand all fo this. I just want the Javascript to check the contents of the DIV where the ID shows through a PHP parameter (E.G $ID would show the ID) then in a message I want to split the data so its ("","") (ID,STUFFLIKEAJAVASCRIPTOPENUP); so it only goes to that user?

Comment: Check the content of what div?  What do you mean by the "id shows through a PHP parameter"?  Then in what message?  Split what data?  And, what is sending to what user?  I read all that in your question, I don't understand at all what it is you're trying to do.  PHP runs server-side.  JavaScript (except for your Node.js application) runs client-side.  What do they have to do with each other?  What's sending what?

Comment: I'd really like it if I showed you on my screenview, I think that's the only way I could get help since I'm not good at explaining things. https://join.me/409-609-166

Comment: @user3818791 I'm signing off for the evening anyway.  Post a screenshot in your question?

Comment: Updated, I don't think the screenshots will help though.